# Multi-signature Ecrow time based?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, accounts, multisignature

I have a **user A** and a **user B**. They do not trust each other. So, they run the following smart contract:

1. User A specify a time locked deposit of x coins to user B under a predefined condition( For example: revealing the correct solution of a function **∅(i)**)
2. If the user B within a specific time T sends a valid solution, so User B gets the deposit.
3. Otherwise, if the user B does not sent any correct solution or misbehave by sending non valid solution. Then, User B get fined with x coins that goes to user A.

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario is basically a mixed up version of `classic` and `multisig` escrow contract.

> Multisignature (multisig) refers to requiring more than one key to
>   authorize a transaction. It is generally used to divide up
>   responsibility for possession.

If User B solved the `∅(i)` in stipulated time `T` then contract releases the escrow, This one is classic example of contract.
The only thing that is new as from your last line is that if user *B* behaves wrongly then some fine will be levied from him. To achieve this both A and B have to deposit some amount of mutual agreed coins to smart contract.

**1.** User A

**2.** user B

**3.** Mutual agreed smart contract rules

A fair implementation of Multisig Smart Contract:

[ConsenSys](https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet)

[gnosis](https://github.com/Gnosis/MultiSigWallet)

Comment: Why we need the Mutual agreed neutral person. The blockchain mainly removes the need for the trusted third parties. This paper allow fair execution with bitcoin  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-44381-1_24  But I am not sure why in your answer specified a third party. I need only 2 parties to agree on the conditions I mentioned in my question.

Comment: with 2 parties there is always fair chance of conflict, See the ETHlend smart contract which is P2p Lending platform : https://etherscan.io/address/0x80fB784B7eD66730e8b1DBd9820aFD29931aab03#code

Comment: @HebaMohsen, i edited my answer : by 3rd person i meant the mutual agreed smart contract rules not person.

Comment: Do you mean:  in bitcoin , 2 users can agree on a transaction, that can be redeemed upon a greed condition. Do you have any idea how that happen on etherum??